# How to fix error "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I want to find out a grade in the program I made.
It highlights the statement `k = k + 1` and says:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Can someone help?

```
Sub SearchStudentData()
    Dim Sname, G As String
    Dim Lname, Lgradetext, position, j, k, position1 As Integer
    Dim gradefile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim Valid As Boolean
    Valid = False
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the student of whom you want the grade!")
    Sname = Console.ReadLine()
    Lname = Len(Sname)
    gradefile = New IO.StreamReader("D:\Grades.txt")
    Do Until gradefile.EndOfStream
        gradetext = gradefile.ReadLine()
        Lgradetext = Len(gradetext)
        j = 0
        k = 0
        Do
            k = k + 1      'It highlights this line of code
            position1 = k
        Loop Until Mid(gradetext, k, 1) = ":"
        Do
            j = j + 1
            position = j
        Loop Until Mid(Lgradetext, j, 1) = ","
        If Sname = Right(gradetext, position1 + 1) And Sname = Left(gradetext, position - 1) Then
            Valid = True
        End If
        If Valid = True Then
            G = Right(Lgradetext, Lgradetext - 1)
            Console.WriteLine(G)
        Else
            Valid = False
            Console.WriteLine("Ypu have failed this PROGRAM")
        End If
    Loop
    gradefile.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not what you expected.  The line from your file has no ":" or "," in it, resulting in an infinite loop, and eventually the error when the counter goes past the max. You could use [String.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) to determine if the value is present, instead of a loop.  When the value is not present, -1 will be returned.  Here's an example:

```
Dim indexOfColon As Integer = gradetext.IndexOf(":")
Dim indexOfComma As Integer = gradetext.IndexOf(",")
If indexOfColon <> -1 AndAlso indexOfComma <> -1 Then
    ' ... both ":" and "," were present in the string, do something with those values ...
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my doubt. God bless!